# Print a selective column after subtraction from another file

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have two files with equal number of rows and columns. I would like to subtract the 2nd column in one file from the 2nd column in another file without considering the missing values. e.g.

```
ifile1.txt    
3  5  2  2
1  ?  2  1
4  6  5  2
5  5  7  1

ifile2.txt
1  2  1  3
1  3  0  2
2  ?  5  1
0  0  1  1
```

Here "?" is the missing value and should not be considered in computation.

```
ofile.txt i.e. [$2(ifile1.txt) - $2(ifile2.txt)]
3
?
?
5
```

I could able to do it **without any missing values** in following way. But can't able to succeed with a missing value like here "?".

```
paste ifile1.txt ifile2.txt > ifile3.txt
awk '{n=NF/2; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%5.2f ", $i-$(i+n); print ""}' ifile3.txt > ifile4.txt
awk '{printf ("%.2f\n",$2)}' ifile4.txt > ofile.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2;next} {print ((a[FNR]$2)~/?/ ? "?" : a[FNR]-$2)}' file1 file2
3
?
?
5
```

Answer (score 1):

POSIX shell script, and **paste**.

```sh
paste ifile[12].txt | \
 while read a b c d  e f g ; do \
       [ "$b$f" -eq "$b$f" ] 2> /dev/null \
         && echo $(( b - f )) \
         || echo '?' ; \
 done
```

Output:

```
3
?
?
5
```